# Computer management through TightVnc

Tags: windows, windows-10, vnc, tightvnc

I remote access to another computer through TightVnc, but in some computer I can not edit computer management / settings. As soon as I open that window I can not click anymore.
The settings are apparently the same both on tightvnc and on the operating system (windows 10) with another computers where it works properly.
The user on remote computer is an administrator and account controll is set to the lowest level.

Do you have any idea what it could be?